# How to read and extract data from .vec file in python

Tags: python, vector

How to read and extract data from `.vec` file in python?

```
f = open("test.vec","r") # opens file with name of "test.txt"
print(f.read())
f.close()
```

But I cant extract the information. I want that the data will be stored in individual arrays in the `test.vec` file.

Comment: Would you mind posting a **short** extract from your data file?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can get some inspiration from this project [here](https://github.com/wulfebw/mergevec). The important part for you starts at [line 131](https://github.com/wulfebw/mergevec/blob/master/mergevec.py#L131), i.e.,

```
...
with open(f, 'rb') as vecfile:  
    content = ''.join(str(line) for line in vecfile.readlines())
    val = struct.unpack('<iihh', content[:12])
...
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my dataset: https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/yekenot/fasttext-crawl-300d-2m

It is Common Crawl 4.2 GB vec file.

Since the file is too big to display in IDE. I read it line by line & export to CSV (17 MB)

```
def load_vectors(fname):
   fin = io.open(fname, 'r', encoding='utf-8', newline='\n', errors='ignore')
   x = fin.readline().split()
   all = []
   while x:
     all.append(x[0])
     x = fin.readline().split()
   df = pd.DataFrame(all)
   df.to_csv('.../output/ft.csv',index=False)
```

Call the function here:

```
FASTTEXT_DATASET_PATH = '/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab Notebooks/pretrained/crawl-300d-2M.vec'
load_vectors(FASTTEXT_DATASET_PATH)
```

The dimension of x is (1999995, 300)

Here I print the first line:
[',', '-0.0282', '-0.0557', ... '-0.0042']

In my case, I just want to export the first element of every list. So I append x[0] to a list named 'all'.
Then I convert it to dataframe & export to csv file.

For those who interested to view how FastText pretrained dataset look like, I've [uploaded it to Kaggle](https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/teohsinyee/word-of-common-crawl-cased-300d-vectors).
The details of dataset: crawl-300d-2M.vec.zip: 2 million word vectors trained on Common Crawl (600B tokens) - Cased

Answer (score -1):

```
with open("file.txt", "r") as ins:
    array = []
    for line in ins:
        array.append(line)
```

Try this one. This is kind of complicated a bit. Otherwise try this simple one.

```
with open('filename') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
```

Comment: It asks for .vec file, not .txt